# Calling a unmanaged C method with a SAFEARRAY **ppsa argument from managed C# code

Tags: c#, vb6, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I've been struggling on how to migrate this VB6 code into C#. It involves calling a function inside a DLL passing an array of structure, among other things.

So in VB6, the "struct" declaration is like this:

```
'Define structure for RGETDAT_STR procedure call
Type rgetdat_str_data_str
    type As Integer                                     'data type (set internally)
    file As Integer                                     'file in database
    rec As Integer                                      'record in file
    word As Integer                                     'word offset in record
    start_bit As Integer                                'UNUSED
    length As Integer                                   'length of string
    flags As Integer                                    'flags
    padding1 As Integer                                 'UNUSED
    value As String                                     'database value
    status As Integer                                   'return status
    padding2 As Integer                                 'UNUSED
End Type
```

and one function that uses this "struct" has a method declared as this:

```
Public Declare Function rgetdat_str Lib "hscnetapi.dll" _
    Alias "rgetdat_str_vb" _
    (ByVal Server As String, ByVal num_points As Integer, _
    getdat_str_data() As rgetdat_str_data_str) As Integer
```

So, I attempted to convert these 2 pieces of code into C#. I had tried so many variations, but I will post here the latest one that I have. The idea is to call the function via [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx).

The C# struct (so far):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct rgetdat_str_data_str
{
    public short type;
    public short file;
    public short rec;
    public short word;
    public short start_bit;
    public short length;
    public short flags;
    public short padding1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string value;
    public short status;
    public short padding2;
}
```

and the function import (so far):

```
    [DllImport("hscnetapi.dll", EntryPoint = "rgetdat_str_vb")]
    public static extern short rgetdat_str(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        string Server,
        short num_points,
         [In,Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
         ref  rgetdat_str_data_str[] getdat_str_data);
```

Nothing worked so far in my various experiments on marshalling attributes with the parameters.

I managed to find the C header file for this DLL, and the declaration looks like this:

```
EXTERN_C short __loadds CALLBACK rgetdat_str_vb_ansi
                _DECLARE((char *szHostname, short cRequests, SAFEARRAY **ppsa));
```

and the "struct" in the C world is declared like this:

```
/* define union used in rgetdat_value in RGETDAT procedure call */
typedef union rgetdat_value_str
{
    n_short         int2;
    n_long          int4;
    n_float         real4;
    n_double        real8;
    n_char          *str;
    n_ushort        bits;
} rgetdat_value;

/* define structure for RGETDAT procedure call */
typedef struct rgetdat_data_str
{
    n_ushort            type;
    n_ushort            file;
    n_ushort            rec;
    n_ushort            word;
    n_ushort            start_bit;
    n_ushort            length;
    n_short             flags;
    rgetdat_value       value;
    n_short             status;
} rgetdat_data;
```

In my frustration, I tried to open this DLL with the ***ITypeLib Viewer*** tool. I was surprised that the DLL file can be opened, even though I cannot add this DLL as a Reference in my project. Anyway, a couple of things that I observed within the viewer.

The function has this signature:

```
[entry("rgetdat_str_vb"), helpstring("...")]
short _stdcall rGetdat_Str(
                [in] LPSTR Server, 
                [in] short num_points, 
                [in, out] SAFEARRAY(rGetdat_Str_Data_Str)* getdat_str_data);
```

and the "struct" looked like this:

```
typedef struct tagrGetdat_Str_Data_Str {
    short type;
    short file;
    short rec;
    short word;
    short start_bit;
    short length;
    short flags;
    short padding1;
    BSTR value;
    short status;
    short padding2;
} rGetdat_Str_Data_Str;
```

Based on these observations, I played around with the marshalling attributes of the C# struct, for example,

1.) Changing the struct's **value** attribute to *[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]*

2.) Changing the function's **getdat_str_data** parameter attribute to *MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_RECORD)*

and still nothing works.

There's an blog/article talking about a similar topic here: http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/marshaling-a-safearray-of-managed-structures-by-pinvoke-part-1/  but I can't just wrap my head around it.

It seems that VB6 can do it very simply compared to C# (.Net) with this DLL function call. Any hints or ideas out there on how to DLLImport declare this function in C# (.Net)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MarshalAs` with `UnmanagedType.SafeArray` to tell the marshaller that you want the array marshalled as a `SAFEARRAY`.

```
[DllImport("hscnetapi.dll", EntryPoint = "rgetdat_str_vb")]
public static extern short rgetdat_str(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    string Server,
    short num_points,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_USERDEFINED)]
    ref rgetdat_str_data_str[] getdat_str_data
);
```

In your C# struct, you handle the `BSTR` member incorrectly. It should be

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public string value;
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I'm still getting the error: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Comment: Break it down to something simpler. Ask yourself how you are going to proceed given `E_INVALIDARG`? Where do you start? Make a new DLL that exports a function that operates on a single value of type `int`. Make sure you can do that. Then move on to, say, a `SAFEARRAY` of `int`. Make sure you can do that. Then move on to a `SAFEARRAY` of a struct with a single `int` member. Make sure you can do that. And so on, building it up step by step. Use the debugger to help when you get stuck.

Comment: re: C# struct, is already a BStr (as pointed out in the last parts of my question, item #1). The only change I made is from VT_RECORD to VT_USERDEFINED as you suggested.  It seems like what I really need here, is how to marshall a pointer of a SAFEARRAY which has user-defined elements (struct) in it. I will do as you suggested, to build a dummy C DLL and go from there.